# Unable to set Deezer playlist to private using api

Tags: deezer

I am working on a project where we create playlists in Deezer using the api, we have been doing this successfully since the call to make it was implemented.  However one of our testers noticed today that the Playlists were no longer private.  I can verify this is the case in the Deezer api explorer and in my code.

- Go to http://developers.deezer.com/api/explorer?url=playlist/4341978# (need to change id to a playlist that your account has created and use getToken feature)
- Change the method to post
- Add parameter public with value of false
- Open console and watch response
  Will return an "Input Error" message

The exact same thing is happening in my code when sending the same kind of request (including the token as a parameter) which has previously definitely worked as intended.

Do you know if the api has changed and I am missing some extra parameters or config? Or possibly there is error which is causing this?

Comment: I had no problem turning one of my playlists into a private one. When you use the getToken feature, do you ask for the "manage_library" permission? This permission is required to modify a playlist's attributes.

Comment: Hey @XGouchet,  thank you for looking.  I cannot replicate the issue any longer and neither can our testers.  Just to prove I am not going mad, can you tell if there were any issues with the api in the last few days?

Comment: I didn't notice any trouble with the API recently. But my guess would be either a bad token or a missing permission.

Comment: Ok, you were not going mad, there was indeed a trouble that was fixed after you posted this question.

Comment: Phew! Thank you for confirming this